# Spring MVC fail to pass large data in JSONArray from controller to JSP page

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a list of department names that are needed to be passed from a controller to the view.  The following code works fine if there are a few department names to be passed, ex. 3 names.  It doesn't work when the number of departments becomes large, for example, 300 names, the first alert in the JSP code doesn't even get invoked in this case.  I printed the length of the JSONArray depNameJSONList from the controller, it shows the correct number of names. The reason I used JSON is because I need to use it in a jquery dataTable.   But why can't it be passed to the view if there are 300 names?  Many Thanks!

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDepartment", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
 public ModelAndView getDepartment()
 {
     ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
     JSONArray depNameJSONList= new JSONArray(departmentNames); 
     logger.debug("depNameJSONList size: " + depNameJSONList.length()); // printed 309
     mv.addObject("depNameJSONList", depNameJSONList);
     mv.setViewName("displayDepartment");
     return mv;
  }
```

JSP:

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
 {
    alert("document ready");
    var depList = $.parseJSON('${depNameJSONList}');      
    alert(depList);  
  });
```

Comment: Why not just render the JSON directly? Try: `var depList = ${depNameJSONList};` Of course you'll want to sanitize your outputs.

Comment: Speaking of sanitizing outputs, do any of your department names have apostrophes? Perhaps O'Sullivan, or D'Arcy?

Comment: yes it does contain apostrophes.  JSON doesn't allow it ?

Comment: @Jlp Is there any error in console when passing the large list?

Comment: Well, you're sticking it inside a single-quoted string, then parsing it. Try just assigning it like I suggested in first comment.

Comment: The reason I used JSON is because later I need to use it in a jquery dataTable.  I have tried using the var depList = ${depNameJSONList};, but it didn't work with the jquery dataTable.

Comment: No, there is no error.  Just the JSP page doesn't show what it should.

Comment: JSP is server side. There's no need to put JSON in a string and then parse it unless you are retrieving it through Ajax. Your `${depNameJSONList}` renders the whole thing inline and sends it out with the rest of the page. Do a view-source in your browser to see what I mean.

Comment: @Tony the Tech, I think you are right, the apostrophes and slash in the department names seem causing the issue.  Any idea how to escape them ?

Comment: @Tony the Tech,  I now use the double quote around ${depNameJSONList} and now I can print all names with the list in javascript.  However, when I want to print individual name, it printed "toJson".  What does that mean ?

Comment: @Tony the Tech, Thank you.  The reason I need to get each individual name is because I need to create a map in javascript, the key is the department name, the value is a list of employees in that department.

Answer (score 1):

I guessyou have some special characters in your JSON string.
In situations like this one, you must be careful in special characters like 'or " or \r or \n or \t; one (or more of thiese characters in the JSON string will throw an error in the JSON.parse method. I can suggest to use org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils class in order to encode the special characters in HTML entities

Comment: Thank you.  But how do I unescape the string from jsp?  It is now displayed &#39; within the string for apostrophes.

Comment: you have several ways; 1) JQuery: varTitle = $('<textarea />').html("&#39;").text(); 2) JSTL:<c:out value="${aString}" escapeXml="false"/> 3) pure JS (this is what I usually use): function parseHtmlEnteties(str) {
    return str.replace(/&#([0-9]{1,3});/gi, function(match, numStr) {
        var num = parseInt(numStr, 10); // read num as normal number
        return String.fromCharCode(num);
    });
}

var str = "&#39;";
alert(parseHtmlEnteties(str));

Comment: by the way....rememeber to remove \n \t and \r (and all their combinations) otherwise JSON.parse will fail